# Sharing MySQLdb transactions across functions

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I'm using MySQLdb to connect to MySQL using python.  My tables are all InnoDB and I'm using transactions.

I'm struggling to come up with a way to 'share' transactions across functions.  Consider the following pseudocode:

```
def foo():
    db = connect()
    cur = db.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute(...)
        conn.commit()
    except:
        conn.rollback()

def bar():
    db = connect()
    cur = db.cursor()
    try:
        cur.execute(...)
        foo()  # note this call
        conn.commit()
    except:
        conn.rollback()
```

At some points in my code, I need to call `foo()` and at some points I need to call `bar()`.  What's the best practice here?  How would I tell the call to `foo()` to `commit()` if called outside `bar()` but not inside `bar()`?  This is obviously more complex if there are multiple threads calling `foo()` and `bar()` and the calls to `connect()` don't return the same connection object.

**UPDATE**

I found a solution which works for me.  I've wrapped `connect()` to increment a value when called.  Calling `commit()` decrements that value.  If `commit()` is called and that counter's > 0, no commit happens and the value is decremented.  You therefore get this:

```
def foo():
    db = connect()  # internal counter = 1
    ...
    db.commit()  # internal counter = 0, so commit


def bar():
    db = connect()  # internal counter = 1
    ...
    foo()  # internal counter goes to 2, then to 1 when commit() is called, so no commit happens
    db.commit() # internal counter = 0, so commit
```

Comment: try extending MySQLdb and going the singleton/factory route (this is what we do in my project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of Python's default function arguments in this case:

```
def foo(cur=None):
    inside_larger_transaction = False
    if cursor is None:
        db = connect()
        cur = db.cursor()
        inside_larger_transaction = True
    try:
        cur.execute(...)
        if not inside_larger_transaction:
             conn.commit()
    except:

        conn.rollback()
```

So, if `bar` is calling `foo`, it just pass in the cursor object as a parameter.

Not that I don't see much sense in creating a different cursor object for each small function - you should either write your several functions as methods of an object, and have a cursor attribute - or pass the cursos explicitly always (in this case, use another named parameter to indicate whether the current function is part of a major transaction or not)

Another option is to create a [context-manager](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#with-statement-context-managers) class to make your commits, and encapsulate all transactions within it - therefore, none of your functions should do transaction commit - you would keep both transaction.commit and transaction.rollback calls on the `__exit__`method of this object.

```
class Transaction(object):
    def __enter__(self):
       self.db = connect()
       cursor = self.db.cursor()
       return cursor
   def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
       if exc_type is None:
           self.db.commit()
       else:
           self.db.rollback()
```

And just use it like this:

```
def foo(cursor):
    ...

def foo(cur):
        cur.execute(...)


def bar(cur):
    cur.execute(...)
    foo(cur)

with Transaction() as cursor:
    foo(cursor)


with Transaction() as cursor:
    bar(cursor)
```

Comment: I like the Transaction() idea! Although as per my comment on Hoopdady's answer, your method would be creating a coupling between the data store and the model which I'm trying to avoid.  Might be able to make some tweaks that don't require the cursor to be passed in explicitly...

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way IMO is to pass the connection object to `foo` and `bar`

Answer (score 0):

Declare you connections outside the functions and pass them to the function as arguements

```
foo(cur, conn)
bar(cur, conn)
```

Comment: I thought of doing this, but I don't like the coupling it creates between the data store and the model.  This would prevent me from refactoring foo()'s internals to use a NoSQL store (for instance).

Comment: I thought in python you cannot pass variables into function as reference...? they are only passed as values..